# numpy ND array: take index'ed elements along a certain axis (ND choose)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I obtain indices along a certain axis. For example like this with 2D and axis=-1 :

```
>>> axis = -1
>>> a = rand(5, 3) - 0.5;  a
array([[ 0.49970414, -0.14251437,  0.2881351 ],
       [ 0.3280437 ,  0.33766112,  0.4263927 ],
       [ 0.37377502,  0.05392274, -0.4647834 ],
       [-0.09461463, -0.25347861, -0.29381079],
       [-0.09642799,  0.15729681,  0.06048399]])
>>> axisinds = a.__abs__().argmax(axis);  axisinds
array([0, 2, 2, 2, 1])
```

Now how can I reduce the array by 1 dimension by taking the indexed elements along that axis?

For 2D and axis=-1   it could be done like this (in order to get the absolute max'es of each row the example array):

```
>>> a[arange(len(axisinds)), axisinds]
array([ 0.49970414,  0.4263927 , -0.4647834 , -0.29381079,  0.15729681])
```

But this is very special and limited to 1 or 0 result dimensions.
How for any `ndim` and `axis` ?

Answer (score 0):

Now I found a simple solution myself:

```
def choose_axis(inds, a, axis=-1):
    return np.choose(inds, np.rollaxis(a, axis))

>>> choose_axis(axisinds, a, -1)
array([ 0.49970414,  0.4263927 , -0.4647834 , -0.29381079,  0.15729681])
```

**Edit:** However this approach turned out to be limited to max 31 elements in the axis direction (32bit?) - because of the (undocumented) limitation of `np.choose`. In many cases this is ok.

Yet this is an

## Unlimited method:

```
def choose_axis(inds, a, axis=-1):
    # handles any number & size of dimensions, and any axis
    if (axis + 1) % a.ndim:            # move axis to last dim
        a = np.moveaxis(a, axis, -1)   # = np.rollaxis(a, axis, a.ndim)
    shape = a.shape
    a = a.reshape(-1, shape[-1])   # 2D
    a = a[np.arange(inds.size), inds.ravel()]  # effective reduction
    return a.reshape(shape[:-1])
```

Thus an ND absolute min example can be done like:

```
def absminND(a, axis=-1):
    inds = a.__abs__().argmin(axis)
    if axis is None:
        return a.ravel()[inds]
    return choose_axis(inds, a)
```